# Send_data returning corrupted files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, sendfile

I have the following download action in my resources controller:

```
def download
    require 'open-uri'

    if validate_token(safe_params[:x])
        resource = Resource.find_by_token(safe_params[:x])
        data = open(resource.file.url)

        send_data( data, :disposition => 'attachment',:url_based_filename => true, type: data.meta['content-type'].to_s)
        #  send_file data, disposition: 'attachment'
        # redirect_to resource.file.url
        puts data.hash
        puts data.meta['x-goog-hash']
    else
        redirect_to pages_error_path, notice: 'Does not match resource.'

    end
end
```

The action downloads a file stored on Google Storage (using `carrierwave`) and then streams that file to the browser.
I tried multiple different configurations of the parameters to send_data and I tried send_file as well. The closest I have come to a working solution is where a PDF file is downloaded but it is corrupt. (Sometimes it accidentally downloads a text document, and rather than the expected file contents I get the memory object of the file as shown below.

```
#<File:0x007fcdda128ea0>
```

I have a feeling the same happens with the PDF download, except that the PDF viewer obviously cannot render that PDF.

I made sure that the URL stored in the database does point to the correct file and the `data` variable is initialized correctly. Everything works as expected up until the point where the data is sent to the browser.

The reason I do this rather than redirecting to the file url is because i dont want to expose the file location on Google storage to the user (hence the temporary download to the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
send_data data.read, disposition: 'attachment', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096'
```

Add in `stream: true`

Comment: Can you provide some explanation please?